# Include field in query but not as aggregated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've the following query in bigQuery:

```sql
    SELECT
    project.name,
    invoice.month,
    service.description,
    project.labels,  <-- error
    (SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CAST(c.amount * 1000000 as int64))
                    FROM UNNEST(credits) c), 0)) / 1000000)*-1
      AS credits,
    (SUM(CAST(cost * 1000000 AS int64))
      + SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CAST(c.amount * 1000000 as int64))
                    FROM UNNEST(credits) c), 0))) / 1000000
      AS cost_after_credits
    FROM `xxxx`
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
    ORDER BY 1 ASC
    ;
```

The query works fine if I remove the `project.labels` but I really need that information. Here's the error I see in the console: `SELECT list expression references project.labels which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [5:3]` if I try to include in the GROUP BY as the `4` field I got: `Grouping by expressions of type ARRAY is not allowed at [14:19]` I know this is because the field is a `record repeated` field. Wondering how to better structure my query to get labels for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

The only "change" in your original script that you need to do is to add ANY_VALUE() aggregate function to the failing line as in below example

```
SELECT
project.name,
invoice.month,
service.description,
ANY_VALUE(project.labels) AS labels,  -- Not failing anymore   
(SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CAST(c.amount * 1000000 as int64))
                FROM UNNEST(credits) c), 0)) / 1000000)*-1
  AS credits,
(SUM(CAST(cost * 1000000 AS int64))
  + SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CAST(c.amount * 1000000 as int64))
                FROM UNNEST(credits) c), 0))) / 1000000
  AS cost_after_credits
FROM `xxxx`
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1 ASC
;
```

Note: no other changes needed - meaning you don't need to add anything into existing GROUP BY!

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is because you can not add a column to the select statement if it is not added to the group by clause, and the second one is because you are trying to group by an array.

To solve that, you can use [TO_JSON_STRING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#to_json_string), the query will look something like this:

```
 SELECT
    project.name,
    invoice.month,
    service.description,
    TO_JSON_STRING(project.labels),
    (SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CAST(c.amount * 1000000 as int64))
                    FROM UNNEST(credits) c), 0)) / 1000000)*-1
      AS credits,
    (SUM(CAST(cost * 1000000 AS int64))
      + SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CAST(c.amount * 1000000 as int64))
                    FROM UNNEST(credits) c), 0))) / 1000000
      AS cost_after_credits
    FROM `xxxx`
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, TO_JSON_STRING(project.labels)
    ORDER BY 1 ASC
    ;
```

Or if you need to preserve the array of labels, you can use [ANY_VALUE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#any_value)

```
SELECT
    project.name,
    invoice.month,
    service.description,
    ANY_VALUE(project.labels),
    (SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CAST(c.amount * 1000000 as int64))
                    FROM UNNEST(credits) c), 0)) / 1000000)*-1
      AS credits,
    (SUM(CAST(cost * 1000000 AS int64))
      + SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CAST(c.amount * 1000000 as int64))
                    FROM UNNEST(credits) c), 0))) / 1000000
      AS cost_after_credits
    FROM `xxxx`
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, TO_JSON_STRING(project.labels)
    ORDER BY 1 ASC
    ;
```

If you want to avoid using GROUP BY, will need to do a left join, being the left side your query and the right side your table (`xxxx` in the example provided)